# sql server 2008 memory caching

Tags: sql-server-2008, caching, memorycache

I have a service that is running and connected to sql server 2008 database, the problem is that i have queries that takes a long time when run for the first time, but when cached it is finishing very fast. Does SQL server 2008 makes automatic clear cache every period of time?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server will not release memory unless there is memory pressure on the server or you explicitly tell it to.

See Microsoft support:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321363

Another cause could be that other database objects which need to be put in memory are pushing the ones you are using out of the buffer. In this case more memory allocated to the instance or more efficient queries will help.

So either there is memory pressure from other applications on the server or you do not have enough memory allocated to the instance for your current workload, but there is not regular scheduled process *per se* that cleans out SQL Server memory buffers.